Creating a clipping tool for a surface mesh
I am trying to create a shader/material that once contacted with a specific mesh, it will reveal the inside of it, similar to this:
enter image description here
So far, I have done it's creating a shader that apply to the mesh itself, but I don't want that because I don't want to change the material of the mesh.
enter image description here
Any ideas on how can I make a material apply to a sphere/plane that cut one specific mesh?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think I managed to solve it.

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MeshClipper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject model3D;
    public Transform planeTransform;
    private Material cuttingMaterial;

    private void Awake() {
        MeshRenderer renderer = model3D.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        cuttingMaterial = renderer.material;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 planePosition = planeTransform.position;
        Vector3 planeNormal = planeTransform.up * -1;

        cuttingMaterial.SetVector("_PlanePosition", planePosition);
        cuttingMaterial.SetVector("_PlaneNormal", planeNormal);
    }
}

